# What's wrong with this LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a simple DTO that I'm trying to return via RIAServices and I keep getting this error:
"Load operation failed for query. Unable to create constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types are supported in this context.

**Here's the query method:**

```
public IQueryable<SupportDbDTO> GetDbsRelatedToModel(string modelDtoId)
{
    IQueryable<SupportDb> query; 

    var key = new Guid(modelDtoId);
    var siteId = _context.SupportDbs.Single(db => db.Id.Equals(key)).SiteDbId ?? Guid.Empty;

    query = _context.SupportDbs
       .Where(db => !db.Id.Equals(key))
       .Where(db => db.DBType == DB.CATALOG_DB || db.DBType == DB.CATALOG_SCHEMA_DB || db.DBType == DB.MODEL_DB)
       .Where(db => db.SiteDbId.Equals(siteId))
       .OrderBy(db => db.DBName);

    return query.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(db => new SupportDbDTO
        {
         Id = db.Id.ToString(),
         DBName = db.DBName,
         DBType = db.DBType,
         PlantRoot = db.PlantRoot,
         DBSize = db.DBSize ?? 0,
         ModifiedDate = db.ModifiedDate ?? DateTime.Now       
        }).AsQueryable();
}
```

I got it to work by using == instead of Equals. This was the offending one:

```
query = _context.SupportDbs
    .Where(db => db.Id != key)
    .Where(db => db.DBType == DB.CATALOG_DB || db.DBType == DB.CATALOG_SCHEMA_DB || db.DBType == DB.MODEL_DB)
    .Where(db => db.SiteDbId == siteId)
    .OrderBy(db => db.DBName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Entity Framework? The LINQ provider for Entity Framework is going to take your LINQ query and directly translate it into SQL. LINQ to SQL probably does the same thing but I've never used it.

So the EF LINQ provider doesn't know how to turn with `Object.Equals()` into a chunk of SQL.

The simplest answer is to do what you are already doing in other places, convert the query into an enumerable with `AsEnumerable()`, then from that point on its no longer an EF query but a LINQ to Objects query, and the whole of LINQ will now work, at the cost of having to pull the whole query out of the database into memory.

But in this particular case, just using `==` looks like it did the trick for you.

Comment: Also doing `query.AsEnumerable().Foo().Bar().AsQueryable()` is a bit counterproductive. Once `AsEnumerable` is called, you're no longer in the DB, so calling `AsQueryable` doesn't do much. You can just return an `IEnumerable` (RIA Services will handle that just fine)

Comment: Thanks I did realise that after posting this...rgds

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if SupportDbDTO is serializable
2. instead of returning IQuerable  return an array(SupportDbDTO[])